# juggle catastrophic expenses

Tags: word-meaning

> Ten years ago, Americans were already sicker, less educated and poorer than the citizens of most other industrialized country. This year an estimated 18 million Americans said that they still could not afford a drug prescribed by their physician. Health care providers and patients **juggle catastrophic expenses** from Covid-19.

> [Source:NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/11/11/opinion/reagan-social-welfare.htm)

What is the definition for the word "juggle" here? I got one - "to manage or alternate the requirements of (two or more tasks, responsibilities, activities, etc.) so as to handle each adequately", not sure whether it works here. On second thought, it seems to mean "toss back and forth (between doctors and patients)", still not sure it is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion of "to manage or alternate the requirements of (two or more tasks, responsibilities, activities, etc.) so as to handle each adequately" is correct.  When a person lacks money, they may have many things they have to pay for.  For example:

1. Rent or Mortgage on their home
2. Food to eat
3. Electricity, Heating, and Water
4. Gasoline or other travel expenses

Often, a person's paycheck is just barely enough to cover the above expenses.  When an additional expense, in this case a medical expense, is added, the person must now **juggle** their expenses.

Juggling expenses means that one or more of the above expenses does NOT get paid.  So maybe one month, they will skip paying rent.  Their landlord will then threaten to evict them.  Just before they are evicted, they stop paying their electrical bill and use that money to pay the rent instead.  The power company threatens to turn the power off, and just before (or shortly after) they do, the person might stop paying the water bill.  When the water gets turned off (or just before), they instead skip several meals, going hungry-- literally starving themselves.  And the juggling continues.

I hope you can see why this is called "juggling", as it is very reminiscent of juggling balls, where at least one ball is "in the air" at all times.  Except with money, the "balls" are bills to pay, and "in the air" means "not paying them on time".

It's a very bad situation to be in, and extremely stressful.